# Does anyone know a regular expression to validate MSISDN-format mobile numbers?

Tags: python, regex, mobile, phone-number

Does anyone know a regular expression to validate MSISDN-format mobile numbers?

I looked into a solution posted at http://charlvn.blogspot.com/2010/06/msisdn-regular-expressions.html but I think that's not a generic solution.

I'm looking for a validation regex that could validate any MSISDN-standard mobile number.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSISDN

Secondly, I'm looking for the means to check whether a valid MSISDN mobile number is from a specific country, like "31628000000" is a number from the netherlands, because it starts with the netnumber "31".

I'm going to implement the validating part in Python.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is the solution in the post you quoted not generic? What constitutes "generic"?

Comment: Maybe could we make a great db?: https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0ApAm-_h2_9kxdEtMaTI3b0xoeWs4T25zbzlod0xzMkE&hl=en

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do -- I'm not sure how much more generic you can get:

```
/^[1-9][0-9]{10,14}$/
```

To check a number to belong to a particular country, modify the pattern to preface the country code, and then adjust the remaining digits to match:

```
/^(873[1-9][0-9]{7,11}|91[1-9][0-9]{8,12})$/    #  India
/^46[1-9][0-9]{8,12}$/                          # Sweden
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  /^[1-9][0-9]{10,14}$/
```

The shortest international phone number is only **7** digits long, e.g. +247 2468.

```
  /^[1-9]\d{6,14}$/
```

Comment: Sorry, but where did you get from this international phone number? What is the country?